# Suggestions for differentiating which Q a user would like to answer

Tags: html, perl

I am trying to make it so that a user can choose which question they want to answer, and, using a textarea, answer that question. I'm having trouble figuring out how I can differentiate which question the user wants to answer. I've tried copying the html code for the textarea form into a variable, and then printing it foreach keys %hash, but I just wind up with syntax errors all over the place. My perl code takes each question in a separate .txt file and stores them into a hash in the form of question/answer pairs. If a question doesn't have an answer, the value is undef., I believe. Does anyone have any suggestions? I'm not asking for a direct answer, but rather some guidance from more experienced or insightful programmers. Any advice is appreciated. Thanks! Here is the most important code:

perl:

```
my @qa_list = ($pagev->listFile($anslist), $pagev->listFile($unanslist));
my %questions = map { split(/\t/, $_, 2) } @qa_list;
my $answer = $cgi->param('answer');

my $questionslist = join("<br>", @qa_list);
my $aselect = $cgi->param('select');
```

html:

```
<form action="/home/megaoff/www/viewquestions.dhtml" method="post">
Add an Answer: <br>
<textarea rows="1" cols="50" name="answer">
Add an answer here
</textarea>
<input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

It's a little scattered right now, mostly because I'm still experimenting with things. But I hope the gist is there: Suggestions for differentiating which question the user wants to answer.

Comment: Do you have drop down list for the questions?

Comment: No, I do not. I'll look into making a drop-down list.